# How do I calculate the average?

Tags: vb.net

So for my code I am trying to calculate the average of the numbers the user has to enter 7 numbers and I want the average to be calculated the after the numbers have been entered. I know that the average is the sum of all numbers divided by how many numbers there are, but I don't know how to actually put that into my code

This is my code:

```
    Dim output As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(InputTextbox.Text, output) Then
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR! Data must be a whole number")
    Else
        UnitsTextbox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & InputTextbox.Text)
    End If
    InputTextbox.Text = String.Empty
    If UnitsTextbox.Lines.Length >= 8 Then
        EnterButton.Enabled = False

        If UnitsTextbox.Lines.Length >= 8 Then
            InputTextbox.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
    If output >= 0 AndAlso output <= 1000 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR! Number must be between 0 and 1000!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

~D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a ListBox to output your numbers, along with a List(Of Integer) as suggested by the others.  Then you can set the DataSource to have the numbers appear for you, like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Units As New List(Of Integer)

    Private Sub EnterButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnterButton.Click
        Dim output As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(InputTextBox.Text, output) Then
            If output >= 0 AndAlso output <= 1000 Then
                Units.Add(output)
                UnitsListBox.DataSource = Nothing
                UnitsListBox.DataSource = Units
                InputTextBox.Clear()

                If Units.Count = 7 Then
                    InputTextBox.Enabled = False
                    EnterButton.Enabled = False

                    ' ... calculate the average in here! ...
                    Dim sum As Integer
                    ' ... fill in the code ...
                    Dim average As Decimal
                    ' ... fill in the code ...
                    lblAverage.Text = "Average: " & average.ToString("N2")

                Else
                    InputTextBox.Focus()
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR! Number must be between 0 and 1000!")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR! Data must be a whole number")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

I've purposely left out the part that calculates the average; you can work that out for yourself...

*Also, take note of the difference in logic flow for the code as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

You have your list of numbers in a TextBox but since they are in the .Text property of the TextBox they are strings not numbers.

1. The first job is to get them out of the TextBox and change them into numbers. That is accomplished in the first For Each adding each entry to a list of Integers.
2. Linq can now calculate the Average in a little bit of code. This is not necessarily faster than the old way that follows.
3. The old way produces the same result.

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)
    For Each line In TextBox1.Lines
        lst.Add(CInt(line))
    Next
    'The Linq way to get Average
    Dim avg = Aggregate number In lst
                  Into Average(number)
    MessageBox.Show($"The Average using Linq is {avg}")
    'EDIT Thanks to Codexer, Linq even shorter code
    Dim avg1 = lst.Average
    MessageBox.Show(avg1.ToString)

    'The old way
    Dim sum As Integer
    For Each number As Integer In lst
        sum += number
    Next
    'Now that you have the sum you can do the division
    Dim avg2 = sum / lst.Count
    MessageBox.Show($"The Average using the old way is {avg2}")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining, thats mainly my problem my teachers dont explain things well enough for me to understand

Comment: @Mary just a slight suggestion IMHO. You can call `.Average` on the list `lst.Average()` which is already a `Linq` extension.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Thank you for the update. I am learning Linq out of an old book and I guessed there would be improvements.

Comment: @Mary you are welcome, the extensions do come in handy at times.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim strA$() = Nothing, Average%, intT%
    'split the text into lines
    strA = Split(TextBox1.Text, vbNewLine)
    'get array length
    For a = 0 To strA.GetUpperBound(0)
        'get the value of the array and summarize
        intT += CInt(strA(a))
    Next
    Average = intT / strA.Length

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?